# Dispatching on correct queue dispatch_get_specific

Tags: ios

I'm looking at other's code and found this:

```
//Obj-C
if (dispatch_get_specific(moduleQueueTag))
    block();
else
    dispatch_sync(moduleQueue, block);
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Swift. Is it required to do this:

```
    if dispatch_get_specific(moduleQueueTag) != nil {
        block()
    } else {
        dispatch_async(moduleQueue) {
            block()
        }
    }
```

or is it okay just to do this:

```
        dispatch_async(moduleQueue) {
            block()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call the `dispatch_sync` function from a task that is executing on the same queue that you pass to your function call. Doing so will deadlock the queue. If you need to `dispatch` to the current queue, do so asynchronously using the `dispatch_async` function.

Also, I followed the link that you provided and in the description of `dispatch_sync` I read this:

I found this in the documentation (last chapter):
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW28